# how to add weekdays to a flutter graph

Tags: flutter

I have created a line chart with the help of the flutter_charts package. but I want to add days of the week in the domain axis of the graph. how can I do this?

> domainAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
> tickProviderSpec:
> charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false),
> viewport: charts.NumericExtents(2016.0, 2022.0),
> ),

I used below code to add years. I want this to be change as weekdays. the picture shows my implementation so far.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'developer_series.dart';

class DeveloperChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<DeveloperSeries> data;

  DeveloperChart({required this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<charts.Series<DeveloperSeries, int>> series = [
      charts.Series(
          id: "developers",
          data: data,
          domainFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.year,
          measureFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.developers,
          colorFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.barColor
      )
    ];

    return Container(
      height: 500,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Yearly Growth in the Flutter Community",
                //style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: charts.LineChart(series,

                          domainAxis: const charts.NumericAxisSpec(
                            tickProviderSpec:
                            charts.BasicNumericTickProviderSpec(zeroBound: false),
                            viewport: charts.NumericExtents(2016.0, 2022.0),
                          ),

                    animate: true),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to generate weekdays in my domain axis how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

The date-time-weeks-days category intervals can be customised using the `interval` and `interval type` properties of `DateTimeCategoryAxis.`

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Container(
                    child: SfCartesianChart(
                        primaryXAxis: DateTimeCategoryAxis(                           
                            intervalType: DateTimeIntervalType.days,
                            interval: 1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }
```

More details on [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types).